# UITableView Selection fade away

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can I give a tableView cell background color the fade effect as soon as it appears. I know how to get a cell selected when the table view appears but the color persists for ever. I would like it to stay there for a while (2 seconds or whatever) and then fade away.

Someone said that I should use [tableView performSelector] so I wrote this:

```
-(void) viewdidLoad {
    [tableView performSelector:@(highlight) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
}

-(void) highlight
{
//I have a row selected as soon as my view appears

    -[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

But when I used it, my application crashed. I think the crashing has something to do with the "withObject" attribute.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `- highlight` method belongs to your controller object, not to the table view. If you change `tableView` to `self` in the second line, it should stop the app crashing.

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSelector:@selector(highlight) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
-(void)highlight{
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

That worked for me, i think you may have missed out @selector() in performSelector. Be careful with the delay as keeping table cells selected after navigating back to the view is not recommended in Apples UI guidelines (as far as i can remember).